# How to flatten array(struct(array))) to array(struct) in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

A DataFrame column contains nested arrays with a nested struct in between (array(struct(array))):

```
root
 |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sub_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to simplify the schema to a single array of struct:

```
root
 |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
```

I am using Spark 3.5.0.

I played around with flatten, inline, explode, transform etc., but without any success.

Update:
I found the following solution, which works for this simplified example:

```
df.select("a", inline("list")) \
.select(expr("*"), inline("sub_list")) \
.drop("sub_list") \
.groupBy("a") \
.agg(collect_list(struct("b", "c", "foo")).alias("list"))
```

But in a more complex scenario this becomes complicated, because it seems that i have to explode ("level up") everything top down to the row level.

I would prefer something like the following (which throws an error):

```
df.withColumn("list", transform(col("list"), lambda x: x.withField("sub_list", explode(x.getField("sub_list")))))
```

In other words:
I would like to explode an inner array into an outer array (bottom up).

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it:

```
df.withColumn(
    "list",
    flatten(
        transform(
            col("list"),
            lambda x: transform(
                x.getField("sub_list"),
                lambda y: struct(x.getField("b"), y.getField("c"), y.getField("foo")),
            ),
        )
    ),
)
```

The logic is:

1. use nested transforms to move column b from outer array to inner
   array
2. flatten transformed arrays to a single array